# Read data from variant template used for queue

Tags: c++

Following code push two structs in one queue.

```
#include <variant>
#include <queue>

struct EventRequest
{
    char EventType;
    int RetryCount;
};

struct EventStatus
{
    char EventType;
    char StatusType;
    short RetryCount;
};

using AnyEvent = std::variant<EventRequest, EventStatus>;

int main()
{
    std::queue<AnyEvent> event;
    
    event.push(EventRequest());
    event.push(EventStatus());

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to read the front of the queue. How do I make a declaration which will return to the front of the queue?

```
?? = event.front();
```

How do I declare the question marked area?

Comment: Have you tried `auto`?

Comment: I am not versed in `std::variant`, but from what it looks like, all you need to do is `AnyEvent item = event.front()` or `auto item = event.front();`.

Comment: Mmm, just `AnyEvent x = event.front();`? I bet you're actually looking for [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `std::visit` as HolyBlackCat point out in comment.

```cpp
    std::visit([](auto& e) { foo(e); }, event.front());
    std::visit([](auto& e) { foo(e); }, event.back());
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5anPsKsaK

Answer (score 0):

So if you are storing `std::varient<EventRequest, EventStatus>` in queue aliasing it `AnyEvent` you will get `event.front()`, `AnyEvent` as well.

So if you want to see which event you get, you can try something like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::queue<AnyEvent> event;
    
    event.push(EventRequest());
    event.push(EventStatus());

    AnyEvent s = event.front();
    try {
        EventRequest er = std::get<EventRequest>(s);
    }
    catch(std::bad_variant_access &exception){
        std::cout << exception.what() << std::endl;
        EventStatus es = std::get<EventStatus>(s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

as if `std::get<T>(variant)` mismatch it will throw, `std::bad_variant_access` exception which you can use to change the type. Moreover `std::get<Index>` works with indexes if you want to access the type laying at particular index of your variant you can access that too.